# GLM conversion from euler angles to quaternion and back does not hold

Tags: opengl, c++, quaternion, glm, euler-angles

I am trying to convert the orientation of an OpenVR controller that I have stored as a `glm::vec3` of Euler angles into a `glm::fquat` and back, but I get wildly different results and the in-game behavior is just wrong *(hard to explain, but the orientation of the object behaves normally for a small range of angles, then flips in weird axes)*.

This is my conversion code:

```
// get `orientation` from OpenVR controller sensor data

const glm::vec3 eulerAnglesInDegrees{orientation[PITCH], orientation[YAW], orientation[ROLL]};
debugPrint(eulerAnglesInDegrees);

const glm::fquat quaternion{glm::radians(eulerAnglesInDegrees)};
const glm::vec3 result{glm::degrees(glm::eulerAngles(quaternion))};
debugPrint(result);

// `result` should represent the same orientation as `eulerAnglesInDegrees`
```

I would expect `eulerAnglesInDegrees` and `result` to either be the same or equivalent representations of the same orientation, but that is apparently not the case. These are some example values I get printed out:

```
39.3851 5.17816 3.29104 
39.3851 5.17816 3.29104 

32.7636 144.849 44.3845 
-147.236 35.1512 -135.616 

39.3851 5.17816 3.29104 
39.3851 5.17816 3.29104 

32.0103 137.415 45.1592 
-147.99 42.5846 -134.841
```

As you can see above, for some orientation ranges the conversion is correct, but for others it is completely different.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I've looked at existing questions and attempted a few things, including trying out [every possible rotation order listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27497022/598696), [conjugating the quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29992778/598696), and other random things like flipping pitch/yaw/roll. Nothing gave me the expected result.

**How can I convert euler angles to quaternions and back, representing the original orientation, using `glm`?**

---

Some more examples of discrepancies:

```
original:      4; 175;   26; 
computed:   -175;   4; -153; 
difference:  179; 171;  179; 

original:     -6; 173;   32; 
computed:    173;   6; -147; 
difference: -179; 167;  179; 

original:      9; 268;  -46; 
computed:   -170; -88;  133; 
difference:  179; 356; -179; 

original:    -27; -73;  266; 
computed:    -27; -73;  -93; 
difference:    0;   0;  359; 

original:    -33; 111;  205; 
computed:    146;  68;   25; 
difference: -179;  43;  180;
```

I tried to find a pattern to fix the final `computed` results, but it doesn't seem like there's one easy to identify.

---

GIF + video of the behavior:

[image: Video excerpt]

- [Full video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSXpWEYKCYU)

---

Visual representation of my intuition/current understanding:

[image: Visual diagram]

- The above picture shows a sphere, and I'm in the center. When I aim the gun towards the green half of the sphere, the orientation is correct. When I aim the gun towards the red half of the sphere, it is incorrect - it seems like every axis is inverted, but I am not 100% sure that is the case.

Comment: What operation are you performing after the round-trip conversion that's revealing unwanted behavior? There's a decent chance the error is there, and the change of angle representation is just making it visible.

Answer (score 4):

The results are not what you expect, but they are not wrong. It’s just that for a given orientation there are at least two “paths” through Euler angles that lead there.

For instance, the identity quaternion is trivially converted to Euler angles `[0,0,0]`. But doing three 180-degree rotations around each axis leaves you in the same orientation, too. That means that `[180,180,180]` is a valid Euler angle representation of that quaternion, too.

Now since your character appears to be a human, it’s probable that their head can’t roll at 180-degree angles, so here is a simple method that you can use to fix your values:

```
if (std::fabs(result.z) >= 90) {
    result.x += 180.f;
    result.y = 180.f - result.y;
    result.z += 180.f;
}
```